# Unrecognised selector sent to instance of UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Created my own subclass of a button, and I'm getting -[UIRoundedRectButton setup]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c3e600'.

I think it's because the buttonWithType just returns a button which isn't of type orange button obviously, but cannot figure out how to do this!

```
  @implementation OrangeButton

    +(id)Create
    {
        OrangeButton *button = (OrangeButton*)[OrangeButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setup];
        return button;
    }

    -(void) setup
    {
        [self setBG];     
    }
    -(void)setBG
    {
        [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-button-orange.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: So basically, i Just round the bounds property rather than created a UiRoundedRectButton ... looks fine, hope its ok

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently.
UIButton is actually a class cluster - i.e. when you instantiate a UIButton, you're likely to get an internal Button class returned (probably different classes depending on the button type but that is an implementation detail). There are several Apple classes like this (NSData is another).

Unfortunately this means it is not (realistically) possible to subclass UIButton. If you need a similar kind of functionality but don't want to / can't use a straight UIButton, A UIView with an attached UITapGestureRecogniser would be my first point of call.

**EDIT:**

Attaching a UITapGestureRecognizer to a UIView provides very similar (and additional extra, e.g. Variable number of taps) functionality to a UIButton. However, instead of writing the following:

```
[someButton addTarget:aTarget action:yourSelector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You need to create and attach the gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:aTarget action:yourSelector];
yourUIView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[yourUIView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
```

If you want to round the edges, add:

```
yourUIView.layer.cornerRadius = 5 // example value
```

To get at the layer property you'll need to import the QuartzCore.h header.

Comment: -If you're after the RoundedRect look - you can adjust the UIView layer's cornerRadius property to get the right shape.

Answer (score 1):

I think its possible, as i have created custom class

In .h, file

```
@interface OrangeButton : UIButton
{
}
-(void) setBG;
@end
```

In .m file

```
@implementation OrangeButton

- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect)frame
{
     self = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

     // set frame
     self. frame = frame;

     if (self) 
     {
        // change bg color   
        [self setBG];

        return self;
     }

    return nil;
}

-(void) setBG
{
    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-button-orange.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Now when you want to use it, call

```
OrangeButton *obj= [[OrangeButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 40)];
[obj setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

// add it to the view
[self addSubview: obj];

// assign action
[obj addTarget: self action: someAction forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I think this will do it